# Why am I obtaining this strange output using the scapy.sniff() function trying to sniff traffic of the opened website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, scapy, packet-sniffers

I am very new in Pyhon (I mainly came from Java) and I am following a Pytohon course applied to security on Udemy in which it is presented an example of packet sniffer implementation using **scapy** module. I am using **Python 3** and this is the structure of my Python project with the scapy version highlighted:

[image: understandable]

It seems to work but I have some doubts related to the output of this application.

This is my source code of my script:

```
#!usr/bin/env python

# INSTALL THE FOLLOWING PYTHON MODULES:
# - pip3 install scapy
# - pip3 install scapy_http

import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http

#
def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)


def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    #print(packet)
    # Check if our packet has HTTP layer. If our packet has the HTTP layer and it is HTTPRequest.
    # In this way I am excluding some garbage information in which I am not interested into.
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        print(packet)

sniff("eth0")
```

So this script sniff the traffic on the **eth0** port and by the content of this if statement:

```
if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
    print(packet)
```

it print only the packet related to the **HTTP** layer avoiding to print other garbage information in which I am not interested.

So I execute the script launching this command into my Linux shell:

```
python3 packet_sniffer.py
```

and the script wait until I open a website into the browser and I obtain an output like this:

```
root@kali:~/Documents/PycharmWS/packet_sniffer# python3 packet_sniffer.py
b"\x00PV\xfd\xa9B\x00PV)\x97\xc7\x08\x00E\x00\x01\x9d\xdb\x84@\x00@\x06\x18*\xc0\xa8\xdf\x85\xd8:\xcdC\x90$\x00Pe\xa7\xb3\x8eM\xf9Y\xd6P\x18\xf9\x8aG<\x00\x00POST /gts1o1 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ocsp.pki.goog\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0\r\nAccept: */*\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nContent-Type: application/ocsp-request\r\nContent-Length: 83\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n0Q0O0M0K0I0\t\x06\x05+\x0e\x03\x02\x1a\x05\x00\x04\x14BF0\xc2'\x19\xdb\xdep\xf0\x8f\xfcs\xe5\xa6_f8\x17\xbc\x04\x14\x98\xd1\xf8n\x10\xeb\xcf\x9b\xec`\x9f\x18\x90\x1b\xa0\xeb}\t\xfd+\x02\x10Qn\xe3\x01\xd1(\xfa$\x08\x00\x00\x00\x002\n\x81"
```

Here I have some doubt:

1) Why am I obtaining this strange string as output? On the Udemy tutorial there is a more understandable output showing information of the package as such as **refereres**, **User-Agent**, **Host** in a more clear way. What is all these **\x..** value in my output? It seems to me that it is coded in some way but I am absolutly not sure about this.

2) Opening different web sites sometimes it provide me the output after that a specific website was opened but some other time it give me no output. How is it possible?

3) Is it working only over HTTP or it is sniffing also over HTTPS?

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can it ry to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Python and Scapy! You have 4 questions here, which would make this question too broad to answer well. The first 3 can be answered easily, but the fourth (the edit) needs to be moved to a separate question (or be removed).

Comment: @RossJacobs removed the section related to Python 2

Comment: If you think this answers your question, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

### Question 1

#### What are Python byte arrays?

That's the [byte array](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) of the packet. "\x55" means 01010101. In python, a bytes object is like a string, but prepending with `b` like `b"bytes"` or `b'bytes'`.

As an example, if we take the first 4 bytes of the bytearray that was printed,
and write it to a file, we can see the bytes representations according to xxd.

```sh
$ python -c 'f=open("temp", "wb");f.write(b"\x00PV\xfd");f.close()'
$ xxd temp
00000000: 0050 56fd                                .PV.
```

Here,

- `b"\x00P"` => `0050`
- `b"V\xfd"` => `56fd`

The 2nd char, `P` in the byte array, is the hex representation of the [ASCII char](http://www.asciitable.com/) `P`.

So you are getting this output because you are printing the bytes of the packet. If you want to print a different representation.

#### How to print packets in scapy

Use `packet.show()` instead of `print(packet)` to have scapy analyze it for you.

Output will look like this:

```sh
$ python script.py
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst       = cc:65:ad:da:39:70
  src       = 6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7
  type      = IPv6
###[ IPv6 ]###
     version   = 6
     tc        = 2
     fl        = 131466

...
###[ HTTP 1 ]###
###[ HTTP Request ]###
           Method    = 'GET'
           Path      = '/online'
           Http_Version= 'HTTP/1.1'
...
```

You could use `print(packet.summary())` instead to get something like this per packet:

`Ether / IPv6 / TCP / HTTP / 'GET' '/online' 'HTTP/1.1'`

Scapy packet object documentation is [here](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.packet.html), and to see the methods/attributes of an object in Python, use `dir(Object)`.

### Question 2

HTTP is a different protocol than HTTPS. Scapy listens for HTTP with that filter and drops HTTPS.

### Question 3

Correct. See 2.

---

Ultimately, if you want to capture all of the packets, don't use a filter. There are ways to decrypt HTTPS packets, but that's for a different question ;)